# Connection to an SFTP via apache camel

Tags: java, kotlin, ftp, apache-camel

Usually I connect to the Sftp server via camel route, but the problem is that in this ftp I don't have permission to delete the files and every day I have to take the file of the day, so I wanted to connect via code and then check the upload date:

```
val sftp = FTPSClient()

private fun sftpConnection() {
    try {
        sftp.connect(host, port)
        sftp.login(user, password)
        sftp.enterLocalPassiveMode()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        logger.error("Error connecting to SFTP: ${e.message}", e)
    }
}
```

in this way the connection did not work, can anyone tell me how I could do it?

Comment: Maybe you could use idempotent repository to avoid fetching same files again in normal camel route.

Comment: what would this be?